# Simple Properties in Objective-C Classes

Tags: objective-c, class, properties, instance

I've bene working with Objective-C for a while now, and so far I have never really needed to craft my own classes, properly.

I am a bit confused with the two arguments you can give the `@property(a, b)` declaration in a header file. When creating outlets to Interface Builder I usually do `@property(nonatomic, retain)` but I have no idea what this means.

I'm writing a simple class which has a set of properties which will be set from the outside, like `[instance setName:@"Bla Bla Bla"];` or I guess like `instance.name = @"Bla@"` but I would rather the first option.

How would I declare this kind of property on a class?

Thanks in advanced!
Sorry for the n00bish question :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The @property parameter gives you a hint on the property behavior:

nonatomic tells you that setting/getting the property value is not atomic (wrt to multiple thread access)

retain tells you the object will be retained by the property (i.e. The receiver will take ownership of the object). The othe options are "copy" (the object is copied using -copy. This is generally the good choice for value objects like NSStrings) and "assign" (the object is just assigned to the property without retaining it. This is generally the good choice for delegates or datasources). These 3 options are only useful for ObjC objects, not simple C type properties.

See http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProperties.html for more info.

For your case, you'll likely use:

```
@property(copy) NSString* name;
```

Or:

```
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString* name;
```

If you don't need the property setter/getter to be atomic.

Comment: `nonatomic` actually tells you that the property is *not* atomic. That means the generated setter/getter will not be wrapped in an `@synchronized` block. This is faster but potentially dangerous when dealing with multiple threads. Generally nonatomic is the way to go due to its speed, at least on iOS (that is, unless you really need to be safe for threading. Most don't).

Comment: Right... Stupid typo. Fixed it.